# How to capture whole screen with camera in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, camera, fullscreen

I have an application in which i open camera without camera controls and i used my custom controls.
Now i want that camera capture whole screen and my custom controls display in front of camera view but don't know how to do that.
Below is my code

```
-(void) cameraOpen
{
    imgpicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imgpicker.delegate=self;
    imgpicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imgpicker.showsCameraControls=FALSE;
    imgpicker.wantsFullScreenLayout=TRUE;

    UIView *newView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,416,320,480)];
    newView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [newView addSubview:cameraOptionView];
    imgpicker.cameraOverlayView=newView;

    [self presentModalViewController:imgpicker animated:YES];
}
```

What happen currently is at bottom it shows white space and my new view in that space.
I want whole screen captured by camera and my custom view for controls should on front of camera.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly you want to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a full screen camera since the the camera aspect ratio (4:3) is not the same as the one as the screen (2:3).

You can however, stretch the image so that it will fill the screen. I do not recommend that, since the image will probably not look right. For that, you'll use [AV Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008072), [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009524) in particular.